# which method are able to approximate the following sequence 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 5x0 1 6x0

Tags: machine-learning

I'm learning deep learning and machine learning techniques, but it looks like neural networks are not capable of predicting the next element in the sequence `1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 5x0 1 6x0`

Is any other method from machine learning sphere, that can predict next value in such sequences?

Code implementation for the sequence

```
def sequence() {
    i = 0
    while (true) {
       yield 1
       for j in range(i):
            yield 0
       i += 1
    } 
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to AI Stack Exchange. I think this question might be interesting, but it is not really clear what you are aiming for. If that was the only sequence, it would be easy to predict. Could you explain what your set of all possible sequences that might need to be predicted is pulled from - maybe in the form of a few Q&A examples. I can see there is some "logic" to the sequence, and it reminds me a little of non-verbal reasoning IQ tests, but it is possible you are looking for a very general AI that can apply some form of Occam's Razor?

Comment: For an example of a sequence that is non-obvious, but that would fit your question: https://oeis.org/A269303 - and OEIS has over 1000 different sequences that contain 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 but do not have 7 next . . . and these are all notable sequences that follow some kind of consistent internal logic.

Comment: Hi, assume this is the only  sequence, so it can be implemented as in the the code(I've just attached to the question)
I’m actually not so profficient in AI, I’ve tried some simple Neural Networks models,
but it looks like they are unable to predict this sequence. So I wonder if exist any method that can predict next value in this sequence?
by the way, I’ve also tried this problem in GPT3(not sure if it’s suitable for this), but it also failed to predict it

Comment: Regarding problem you provided, it look interesting,  but I think it is too complex for any known method to approximate it, I’m not sure if even human can do this

Comment: Yes I thought of GPT-3, tried it on your problem unsuccessfully, although it can solve shorter versions of this and other simple logic tests.